# Как сделать выборку строки по двум столбцам с помощью LINQ C#

Tags: c#, linq

Пожалуйста, помогите мне создать запрос LINQ, чтобы взять одну запись из базы данных с минимальным значением из столбца `tax_money` и свежим временем из столбца `LastUpdateTime`. Согласно скриншоту, нам нужно извлечь данные из строки 5 на основе условия

Скрин
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Отсортируйте по двух столбцам да возьмите первый. Чет по типу `.OrderBy(x => x...).ThenBy(x=>x....).First();` Скорей всего понадобится обратная сортировка (`OrderByDescending()` и `ThenByDescending()`). Правда не знаю, как это поведет себя с базой.

Comment: О, спасибо за помощь. Сделал на EF Core так:
 `var City = await db.Parameter_City.OrderBy(t => t.Tax_Money).ThenByDescending(t => t.LastUpdateTime).FirstOrDefaultAsync();`